# Pass Textarea content into an existing form

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have this item added on cart with the option for the user to tell any further info on that article

[Item Textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrrym.png)

Upon firing the 'click' event a sweetalert modal popsup with a textarea for the user to deliver more information

[Sweetalert popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3W0r.png)

How would i pass in the information inserted by the user inside this textarea into an existing form?
Once they checkout, a Checkout-Form appear on the left side to prompt the user to give his contact information

[Checkout-Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1eDb.png)

```js
function TextArea() {

  Swal.fire({
    title: '<strong>Bemerkung</strong>',
    input: 'textarea',
    inputPlaceholder: "Wir geben unser Bestes den Wunsh zu erfüllen"
  })


}
```

```css
.cart_item {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start
}

.cart_item_description {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 18px;
  margin-left: 18px;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.text-block-14 {
  font-weight: 700px;
}

.remove_button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5df78d3035688c75f8199fe6/5f37a16d65d8f8df2ca7dafa_trashopenoffice.svg);
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.w-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0
}

.bemerkung {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: -24px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5df78d3035688c75f8199fe6/5f3830b87c03d7ae736cc485_pen%20loading-editing.svg);
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.cart_quantity {
  width: 60px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 12px;
  border: 0 solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f7f8f9;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0 rgba(158, 164, 172, .25), -3px -3px 4px 0 #fff;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart_item">
  <div class="cart_item_description">
    <div class="text-block-14">Caprese</div>
    <div class="cart-price">$10</div>
    <div class="dressing">Dressing</div>
    <button class="remove_button w-button" type="button"></button>
    <button class="bemerkung w-button" type="button" onclick="TextArea()"></button>
  </div>
  <input class="cart_quantity" type="number" value="1">
</div>


<!--------------------MODAL------------------------------ -->
<!--------------------JqueryForm------------------------------ -->
<iframe src="Checkout/form.html" scrolling="yes" id="checkout" style="min-width:280px;width:100%;height:600px;border:none;" frameborder="none" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
<!-- ----------------------------------------------- -->

<!-- Modal Popup-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davon924/6rzfwjoL/23/

Comment: Show the full code IN the question not just a fiddle link please.- this can be done as a snippet that will actually run the code similar to a fiddle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [SweetAlert docs](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples), the `swal()` method returns a promise when the modal's action is completed.

You can simply access the textarea contents like this:

```js
function TextArea() {

  Swal.fire({
    title: '<strong>Bemerkung</strong>',
    input: 'textarea',
    inputPlaceholder: "Wir geben unser Bestes den Wunsh zu erfüllen"
  }).then(result => {
    const string = result.value;

    // You can now create a new hidden input node in that target form;  
    const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.value = string;
    hiddenInput.name = /* appropriate name */;

    document.querySelector( /* form selector */ ).appendChild(hiddenInput);
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks @buttons it is working as needed. So Sweetalert2 returns the value and saves into it into the variable `string` and from there i create an input to further append into the form. I understand it correctly.